# ReadDirectoryChangesW всегда возвращает 0

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно отследить изменения в каталоге и его подкаталогах. Для этого использую функцию `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, но она постоянно возвращает `0`. В чем может быть дело?

```
FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION strFileNotifyInfo[1024];
DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0; 
while(true){
    if(ReadDirectoryChangesW(L"D://ServerCatalog1" /*options.catalog*/, strFileNotifyInfo, sizeof(strFileNotifyInfo), true, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME || FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME || FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE, &dwBytesReturned, NULL, NULL) != 0){
        printf("Mod: %s\n", strFileNotifyInfo[0].FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. Взято отсюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Наверное лучше так написать: FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE. Побитовое или. А также: If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Comment: GetLastError выдает 6 т.е. неверный дескриптор.
Я так полагаю, это из-за того что проект в мультибайтовой кодировке, а функция работает с юникодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Был невнимателен. В ReadDirectoryChangesW первым параметром нужно передавать HANDLE

```
HANDLE hDir = CreateFile("D://ServerCatalog1", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

while(true){
    if(ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir, strFileNotifyInfo, sizeof(strFileNotifyInfo), true, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE, &dwBytesReturned, NULL, NULL) != 0){
        printf("Mod: %s\n", strFileNotifyInfo[0].FileName);
    } else {
        Error = GetLastError();
    }
}
```